# Где найти значения протоколов struct iphdr->protocol C

Tags: c

Подскажите пожалуйста. Где можно посмотреть значения протоколов struct iphdr?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь - /usr/include/netinet/in.h (или http://repo-genesis3.cbi.utsa.edu/crossref/ns-sli/usr/include/netinet/in.h.html , если нет доступа к линукс машине, с 30 по 90 строку).

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо.)

Comment: Когда есть доступ к *nix машине, то еще в /etc/protocols

Comment: Еще раз большое спасибо)

Comment: А не могли бы вы подсказать еще пожалуйста, что за протокол со значением 40? Не могу его найти почему-то в списках.

Comment: я тоже его не вижу. Либо это с ошибкой записно, либо какой то кастомный протокол в самосборном юниксе.

Где Вы взяли это 40?

Comment: Но судя по rfc, это некий [IL Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IL_(network_protocol))

Comment: Да я тоже посмотрел уже. Я просто в учебных целях пишу сниффер используя пакетные сокет си. И для понимания хотелось разобрать каждое значение которое встретилось мне при работе сниффера. Как только я его включил мне завалило экран пакетами с номером протокола 40 и стало очень интересно что же это такое)